# Need Help Optimizing SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization

First I would like to say that I'm fairly new to SQL so this might seem like a stupid question.
So in this code I receive a Date as a parameter, add 61 minutes to it and check the values in between.
Then I Sum the values from each column and store it in another table.
The Code is Working just fine, what I would like to know is if there is a better way to do it and how to do it.(Without using so many lines or repetitive code)

Thanks in advance.

```
alter procedure Contagem
@date datetime

as
begin
    declare
    @Sala1 float,
    @Sala2 float,
    @Sala3 float,
    ...
    @Sala26 float,
    @Sala27 float,
    @Sala28 float,
    @dateplus datetime

    set @Teste = 1
    set @dateplus =  (select DATEADD(MINUTE,61,@date))

    set @Sala1 =  (select sum(Sala_1_Energia) from Energia_15min where Time_Stamp between @date and @dateplus)
    set @Sala2 =  (select sum(Sala_2_Energia) from Energia_15min where Time_Stamp between @date and @dateplus)
    set @Sala3 =  (select sum(Sala_3_Energia) from Energia_15min where Time_Stamp between @date and @dateplus)
    ...
    set @Sala26 =  (select sum(Sala_26_Energia) from Energia_15min where Time_Stamp between @date and @dateplus)
    set @Sala27 =  (select sum(Sala_27_Energia) from Energia_15min where Time_Stamp between @date and @dateplus)
    set @Sala28 =  (select sum(Sala_28_Energia) from Energia_15min where Time_Stamp between @date and @dateplus)

    Insert into Custos_hora values (@date,@Sala1,@Sala2,@Sala3,@Sala4,@Sala5,@Sala6,@Sala7,@Sala8,@Sala9,@Sala10,@Sala11,@Sala12,@Sala13,@Sala14,@Sala15,@Sala16,@Sala17,@Sala18,@Sala19,@Sala20,@Sala21,@Sala22,@Sala23,@Sala24,@Sala25,@Sala26,@Sala27,@Sala28)
end
```

Comment: You really need to read up on normalization. You have repeating columns which makes things very difficult to work with. You could certainly make this perform better by setting all the variable in a single select statement instead of hitting the same table over and over. But really the best option would be to completely refactor this table into a normalized table structure.

Comment: @Dumbrica: The best answer you have got so far is Sean Lange's comment in my opinion.

Comment: Another concern here is that you are using SUM on a float. That is an indication that you want some sort of precision on these values. The float datatype is an approximate datatype and cannot hold every value. If you want accuracy you should consider switching out to decimal or numeric instead.

Comment: @SeanLange Alright, Thank you, Ill read into it. As for the variables ill change the datatype to decimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just hit that table the once rather than 28 times as you are currently doing.

```
INSERT INTO Custos_hora
SELECT
SUM(Sala_1_Energia)
,SUM(Sala_2_Energia)
,SUM(Sala_3_Energia)
,SUM(Sala_4_Energia)

FROM Energia_15min

WHERE Time_Stamp between @date and @dateplus
```

It's considered best practice to declare the fields that you're inserting into like this;

```
INSERT INTO Custos_hora (Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4)
SELECT
SUM(Sala_1_Energia)
,SUM(Sala_2_Energia)
,SUM(Sala_3_Energia)
,SUM(Sala_4_Energia)

FROM Energia_15min

WHERE Time_Stamp between @date and @dateplus
```

Also, what's the variable `@Teste` for? it doesn't appear to be being used anywhere. And you don't seem to be declaring `@date` either.

Comment: Ignore @teste, I was using it earlier to test some things and forgot to delete it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure we've all been there with test code :) If any of these answers have helped then please feel free to upvote them. Also if you could mark one as the accepted answer then it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do the following instead:

```
Alter Procedure Contagem (@Date DateTime)
As Begin
    Insert  Custos_hora
    Select  @Date,
            Sum(Sala_1_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_2_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_3_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_4_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_5_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_6_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_7_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_8_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_9_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_10_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_11_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_12_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_13_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_14_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_15_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_16_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_17_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_18_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_19_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_20_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_21_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_22_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_23_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_24_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_25_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_26_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_27_Energia),
            Sum(Sala_28_Energia)
    From    Energia_15min
    Where   Time_Stamp Between @Date And DateAdd(Minute, 61, @Date)
End
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiple SELECT statement will make multiple table scan and increase disk IO and memory utilization. It can be done in single select statement.

```
    alter procedure Contagem
      @date datetime

      as
      begin


      declare
      @Sala1 float,
      @Sala2 float,
      @Sala3 float,
      @Sala4 float,
      @Sala5 float,
      @Sala6 float,
      @Sala7 float,
      @Sala8 float,
      @Sala9 float,
      @Sala10 float,
      @Sala11 float,
      @Sala12 float,
      @Sala13 float,
      @Sala14 float,
      @Sala15 float,
      @Sala16 float,
      @Sala17 float,
      @Sala18 float,
      @Sala19 float,
      @Sala20 float,
      @Sala21 float,
      @Sala22 float,
      @Sala23 float,
      @Sala24 float,
      @Sala25 float,
      @Sala26 float,
      @Sala27 float,
      @Sala28 float,
      @dateplus datetime

     set @Teste = 1
     set @dateplus =DATEADD(MINUTE,61,@date))

    Insert into Custos_hora
      select sum(Sala_1_Energia),
      sum(Sala_2_Energia),
      sum(Sala_3_Energia),
      sum(Sala_4_Energia),
      sum(Sala_5_Energia),
      sum(Sala_6_Energia),
      sum(Sala_7_Energia),
      sum(Sala_8_Energia),
      sum(Sala_9_Energia),
      sum(Sala_10_Energia),
      sum(Sala_11_Energia),
      sum(Sala_12_Energia),
      sum(Sala_13_Energia),
      sum(Sala_14_Energia),
      sum(Sala_15_Energia),
      sum(Sala_16_Energia),
      sum(Sala_17_Energia),
      sum(Sala_18_Energia),
      sum(Sala_19_Energia),
      sum(Sala_20_Energia),
      sum(Sala_21_Energia),
      sum(Sala_22_Energia),
      sum(Sala_23_Energia),
      sum(Sala_24_Energia),
      sum(Sala_25_Energia),
      sum(Sala_26_Energia),
      sum(Sala_27_Energia),
      sum(Sala_28_Energia) from Energia_15min where Time_Stamp between @date and @dateplus
      end
```